# Website is not accessible after GCP instance upgrade

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform

I have upgraded the GCP instance from 1 shared CPU 1.7GB RAM to 1 CPU 3.75 RAM. After the upgrade the website is not accessible. I can access the instance with SSH and FTP, but not on port 80. The firewall is set to Allow: 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you upgrade an instance with an ephemeral IP address the IP address may change.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your instance or project have lost firewall configuration for http and https traffic. 
By default, ports tcp:80 and tcp:443 are allowed in GCP firewall configuration.  Please find [this document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) providing detailed information about GCP firewall. You can review, edit, add, remove firewall rules as per [this document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#viewing_firewall_rules_details).
Make sure firewall at instance level is not blocking http and https traffic. Please review and [set-up an external HTTP(s) connection at an instance](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#externalhttpconnection) level. Nevertheless, make sure that the instance iptables are not blocking the traffic. You may want to perform port scanning using nmap -Pn {external IP} command to test and verify firewall connection for port 80 and 443 from the external network.